# how do i display only assigned to the product attribute value?

Tags: magento

im using https://github.com/witrin/magento-attribute-option-image/ and trying to get on product view page image and thumbnail of attribute by using this code

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
$_options = $_attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

foreach ($_options as $_option) {
    echo $_option['image'];
    echo $_option['thumbnail'];
}
```

so it shows me all options of that attribute and not the assigned to product

how do i display only assigned to the product value of the attribute?

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should correct it by the following way:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
$_options = $_attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

foreach ($_options as $_option) {

    //is this value assigned to the current product?
    if ($_product->getColor() == $_option['value']) {
        echo $_option['image'];
        echo $_option['thumbnail'];
        break; //we found it, no reason to continue searching
    }
}
```